# JavaScript : mouseout event in Popup Bubble causing children to hide

Tags: javascript, css, events, dom-events

I have a problem with some event propagation. When I `mouseover` a child element in `description` div, the `description` div as well as `mouseovered` child gets `display:none;`. After this event occurs selected child will remain invisible until page refresh.
Here is a "working" demo:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NightKn8/gfvq9yvp/4/)

I believe that the main cause of this is somewhere between lines 8-15 of my JS code on jsfiddle where the`mouseout` triggers immediately in case of not finding `description` div under mouse cursor.

I have found not elegant workaround by adding `:before` to `description` div in my css. You can find this workaround commented in jsfiddle CSS section. This unfortunately prevents of doing anything in the Popup Bubble (like `href` clicking). I want to keep this simple and functional, without any workarounds.

Comment: Is the problem that `<div id="left">Text</div>` disappears?

Comment: yes, as well as `<div id='description'></div>` disappears when you `mouseover` `<div id="left">Text</div>`. The correct behaviour would be that after `mouseovering` the element `<div id="left">Text</div>` both elements remain visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouseleave and target this instead of e.target.
e.target will equal what you are hovering.

https://jsfiddle.net/gfvq9yvp/6/

```
     e.target.children[a].addEventListener("mouseleave",function(e){
         this.style.display="none";
     }, false);
```

Comment: they still disappear

Comment: I have tested your answer in actual code - works perfectly. Thank you!